# How can you read a boolean array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, local-storage, storage

I have this boolean array that I am using in my app, but I have no idea how to save this array that I am using. Here is how I am saving the array:

```
public void writeArraytofile() {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("array.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            outputStreamWriter.write(array[i] + "");
        }
        outputStreamWriter.flush();
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("MyActivity", e.toString());
    }
}
```

I have searched everywhere on how to read this array and access it after the user restarts the app. And one of the things that I would not like to use is Sharedpreferences because when I uninstall my application when using the Sharedpreferences after I reinstall, it doesn't work anymore. So anything without the use of Sharedpreferences would be awesome.

Please and Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question with the structure of the file.

Comment: @Vilsol you want me to add the actual file?

Comment: No, you only need to add the structure of the file not the whole file.

Comment: Why not just write `array` in its entirety, with a single call to `write`? (i.e. `outputStreamWriter.write(array)`)  That'd make it much easier to read back out.

Comment: @Vilsol im not sure how to do that. Maybe, you can help me find it.

Comment: @AndyTurner okay, I'll do that, but how do I read that?

Comment: @Vilsol when I print out the string of the file its just TrueFalse. Btw the array is the size of 2

Comment: @AndyTurner and when I tried to do that it wouldn't let me

Comment: @AndyTurner That doesn't even compile.

Comment: @JohnSolly You should look into Serialization.

Answer (score 0):

You could write as `boolean + ","` and when reading `String[] xyz = read.split(",")` and loop through that to reintialize the boolean array.

I can't say this is the most efficient, but its the only thing that comes to mind.

Answer (score -2):

A simple way to save data in file with stream :
Make a class *(for example **mydata**)* and implement **Serializable** . Make *property* in this class **ArrayList array** .
Now you can write your object with type **mydata** to file, and read with streamereader easily. When you read the file, stream reader load your object and you can use the **array property** .

Reguards 
A.Ayati

Comment: `boolean[]` is already `Serializable`. There is no need for another class.

Comment:  It was just a guide for all classes